# PyQGIS in PysScripter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to add the PyQGIS in PyScripter, I have followed the tutorial provided in QGIS tutorial: [IDE settings for writing and debugging plugins](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/ide_debugging.html?highlight=ide). I have created the bat file as follows:

```
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
SET PyScripter="C:\Program Files\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe"

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM PYTHONHOME: %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
REM PYTHONPATH: %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages

start "script" /B %PyScripter% %*"
```

The error message appears again:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'`.

Note: I am using QGIS 3.10  and python 37.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the qgis batch file as a template.

```
@echo off
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET PyScripter="C:\Program Files\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe" 

call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat" 
call qt5_env.bat 
call py3_env.bat 

path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%\bin;%PATH% 
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/%QGISNAME%
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES 
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448 
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE 
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000 
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins 
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
start "PyScripter" "%PyScripter%" %*
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas for your reply, I used also this one but it didn't work, the solution is using Eclipse, defining the packages in its preferences and all done

Comment: Oh, i just missed a line to set the pythonpath, as you did in your batch file, edited that it works for me. For the case that anyone else is searching for a solution with PyScripter, could you please check my editet batch file?

Comment: it did not work I had set the python path and OSGEO$W_ROOT but it didnot work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:
Just use Eclipse IDE and add the Pyqgis packages to the PyDev,and it will works!!!

Comment: Be aware that if you want to develop QGIS-Standalone applications or even QGIS-Plugins with python, you'll need parts of that environment, set in the batch files.